# Any way to determine the dimension of matrix given the norm of applied vector?

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, svd

Let $r \in [1, 95]$ and two full rank matrices $W_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{r \times 100}$ and $W_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{100 \times r}$. I can choose any  $x \in \mathbb{R}^{100}$ and obtain result of $$ ||\sin(W_2 \cos(W_1 x))||^2_2,$$where trigonometric functions are applied element-wise.
How can I find out the $r$? I can use numeric calculations using JAX.

Comment: Without any more information on the $W$'s this is impossible: You can always increase $r$ by adding zero-columns to $W_2$ (and arbitrary new rows to $W_1$), without changing any computable values. Therefore the increased $r$ is not detectable. I think the best you can hope for a statistically determining a lower bound on $r$.

Comment: Also: I would assume you mean that $\cos$ and $\sin$ are applied component-wise? maybe you should clarify that in your question.

Comment: @Simon, matrices should be full rank. And yes, operations are element-wise, as is stated after the expression.